# Replace missing predictions with actual values altered by an error

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data

I have two time series:

- One year of the actual values of Y
- My predictions for Y in that year made by someone's guess

The second time series, the one with the predictions, is missing two months.

I would like to fill these two missing months. In order to do it, I would like to use the actual Y values for those two months, but altered so this 2-month period would have similar prediction errors compared to the rest of the year.

What would be a clever way of doing that? I'm thinking in the lines of using the mean quadratic error of the predictions and adding this noise to the actual values of the 2 months.